# VSCode + SVN + Shelf?

Tags: visual-studio-code, svn, tortoisesvn, vscode-extensions

I'm using VSCode on Windows, and the project I'm working on uses SVN.  I'm looking for a VSCode way to see everything that's been shelved.  I know I can shelve my changes with TortoiseSVN, but I can't see what's on the shelf.  Is there a VSCode SVN plugin that will not only allow me to shelve changes within VSCode, but also see all of the shelved changes?  I've looked through many SVN extensions and haven't found anything.  Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Have you had any luck finding an extension?

Comment: @edjm Unfortunately no. My work around has been:

1. Copy my files with my changes to another folder.
2. Back in the project, undo my changes and make what ever new changes I need to make.
3. Finally, compare the updated files with copied files, and move the copied files changes to the updated files.

It's not as nice as a plugin would be, but it works.

Comment: I've been doing the same kind of thing by having a 2nd project folder. Then I use the tool MELD to do a diff between the folders excluding all of the node_modules content. This just sucks. The shelf would be helpful but I can just use the git stash feature command line for now.